# Disable user of multiple same exact numbers in input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have an input box here

```
<input type="text" size="9" maxlength="9" id="my_account" name="my_account" value="" >
```

And I want to disallow users to enter the same numbers in the box? How can I do this ? Thanks in advance

I don't want them to be able to enter numbers like this

```
111111111 
or
55555555
```

Comment: Did you try to write some code yourself? It sound like a homework assignment that you want someone to solve for you.

Comment: create an arrray. push input number in the array on an event fired, check the array . u r done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@edit If you don't want to let user enter these values as he types you may want to verify only when value equals to 2.

You can listen on keydown event of input element and verify it's actual content and pressed number like this:

```
var inputNode = document.getElementById('my_account');

inputNode.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  var inputValue = event.key;
  var inputNodeValue = inputNode.value;
  var length = inputNodeValue.length;

  if (length === 1 && inputNodeValue[0] === inputValue) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

If you want to verify on submit, just get value of first character and check if every other is equal to it.

Comment: this doesnt allow a number to be put in twice

Comment: Seems you are right, there is some error in my logic. Will try to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to find strings that only consist of one consecutive digit:

```js
var validator = /\b(\d)\1+\b/

console.log(validator.test('111')) // true
console.log(validator.test('123')) // false
console.log(validator.test('121')) // false
console.log(validator.test('112')) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

```html
<input type="text" size="9" maxlength="9" id="my_account" name="my_account" value="" pattern="^(?!(\d)\1{8}).*">
```

Notes:

- you did not say you wanted to disallow letters, if you do, just replace `.*` with `\d*`
- I interpreted it as "nine times the same number". If you want to e.g. not allow "3 times same number anywhere", you need to change it to `^(?!\d*(\d)\1{2,}).*`
- If you want to only disallow multiples of a digit without any other extra, add the line termination regex: `^(?!(\d)\1*$).*`

Example for "not 3 times same number anywhere but must be numbers":

```html
<input type="text" size="9" maxlength="9" id="my_account" name="my_account" value="" pattern="^(?!\d*(\d)\1{2,})\d*">
```

Example for "not only the same number multiple times but still numbers":

```html
<input type="text" size="9" maxlength="9" id="my_account" name="my_account" value="" pattern="^(?!(\d)\1*$)\d*">
```

Comment: This won't work for the second example `55555555` with 8 consecutive digits instead of nine.

Comment: I added notes, i slightly misinterpreted the intended allowed numbers i think. Added an example for a more broad matching.

Comment: Also note that the `pattern` attribute is not completely supported by all major browsers, most notably Safari: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Browser_compatibility